# Better replacement for a huge “if x==2 / if x==3 / if x==4” chain REMOVING prefixes and suffixes?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to python. I am making a simple decryption system. I want the first character and the last 4 or 5 characters to be removed (depending on length of password). The only was I can figure this out is to do it with if statements :(. Is there a better way? If there is can someone please explain it?

```
if (len(initialPass)) == 2 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:2]
if (len(initialPass)) == 3 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:3]
if (len(initialPass)) == 4 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:4]
if (len(initialPass)) == 5 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:5]
if (len(initialPass)) == 6 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:6]
if (len(initialPass)) == 7 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:7]
if (len(initialPass)) == 8 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:8]
if (len(initialPass)) == 9 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:9]
if (len(initialPass)) == 10 + 5:
    initialPass = initialPass[1:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:10]
if (len(initialPass)) == 11 + 6:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:11]
if (len(initialPass)) == 12 + 6:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:12]
if (len(initialPass)) == 13 + 6:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:13]
if (len(initialPass)) == 14 + 6:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:14]
if (len(initialPass)) == 15 + 6:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:15]
if (len(initialPass)) == 16 + 7:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:16]
if (len(initialPass)) == 17 + 7:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
   initialPass = initialPass[:17]
if (len(initialPass)) == 18 + 7:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:18]
if (len(initialPass)) == 19 + 7:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:19]
if (len(initialPass)) == 20 + 7:
    initialPass = initialPass[2:]
    initialPass = initialPass[:20]
```

Comment: To ignore only the first character you need to start from 1 not 2, and then just use the minus syntax for the stop position: `initialPass = initialPass[1:-5]`... that works for all of your examples does it not?

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: My first thought when i say if else chains or switch statements (c#, not python...) is a dictionary. Is that a possibility here?

Comment: Google indexing in python.... It explains that the first character is indexed by zero not 1, and that negative indexing starts the index from the end of the string.

Comment: Okay thank you I will do this. But I am asking is there a more sufficient way then just using if statements?

Comment: Doesn't the way I posted above cover all of the if statements in your code? i.e. for all passwords of sufficient length this removes the first character and the last 5. i.e. no need for any if statements.

Comment: length=17 is missing.  Perhaps instead of enumerating it with potential typos you can describe in words what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Posting @Woody Pride's solution as an answer:
This is equivalent to all your code in Python:

```
initialPass = initialPass[1 if len(initialPass) <= 15 else 2:-4]
```

Explanation: Use negative indices for Python's slicing. it is defined as follows:

```
sublist = list[start:end:step]
```

and negative values are to be interpreted as counting from the end.
Please note that indexing starts at 0. So `"Hamster"[1]` is `a`. here are some more examples to clear things up:

```
"Hamster"[1:3]  = "am"
"Hamster"[2:]   = "mster"
"Hamster"[-2:]  = "er"
"Hamster"[2:-2] = "mst"
"Hamster"[::2]  = "Hmtr"
```

Comment: Not all the slices begin at `1`

Comment: Thanks, fixed as well. Didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

Quick code:

```
initialPass = initialPass[1 if len(initialPass) <= 15 else 2:-4]
```

What you're doing with all of your conditions is to start from index 1 all the way to 4 from the end, and python has a nice way of doing this using negative slices.

Comment: Not all the slices begin at `1`

Answer (score 0):

I think this (or some variation of this) should do the trick.

`if len(initialPass)>=17:
        initialpass=initialPass[2:]
        initialpass=initialpass[:len(initialPass)-6]
else:
        initialpass=initialPass[1:]
        initialpass=initialpass[:len(initialPass)-5]`

Answer (score 0):

cut the first char until size 15, afterwards cut the first two.  Cut the last 4 chars.

```
initialPass = initialPass[1 + len(initialPass)/15:-4]
```

this will work while length <= 30, from which it will start cutting first three chars.  Depends on integer division.